# Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have joint density $f(c,y)=6xy^2$ for $x,y\in(0,1)$. What is $P(X+Y<1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

My attempt: 
$$f(x,y)=6xy^2$$
$$P(X+Y<1)=\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^{1-y} 6xy^2dxdy$$
$$=\frac{1}{10}$$

However, the answer was supposed to be $\frac{3}{5}$, and the bounds on the integral were supposed to be $\int_0^1\int_0^{y}$ (everything else I did correctly). Why is this so? Every way I work the problem I get the same answer

Comment: Why the answer is supposed to be $3/5$? Is that what the solution says? Your answer is correct.

Comment: I don't know, the solution just says $3/5$. I am thinking it might be a mistake but I don't know.

Comment: $\int_0^1\int_0^{y}$ will give you $P(X<Y)$. Your bounds and answer is correct.